# Triple space and Triple store in java and Jena framework

Tags: rdf, jena, semantic-web, triplestore

just a straightforward question

what are differences between Triple store and Triple space

I am doing a project that uses Jena as a framework which deals with RDF triples and wondering where I should store them. As a fact that I am trying to avoid using schema-less databases such as MongoDB,without obvious reason.

I like the ideas of Triple space computing

I have always thought that, the triple space computing as an existing shared storage , yet I do not find any implementation for such a thought. maybe I hold a misconception.

here some interesting links I found so far

D21.v0.1 WSMX Triple-Space Computing

```
http://www.wsmo.org/TR/d21/v0.1/
```

tsc++

```
http://tsc.sti2.at/
```

this plus different middle-wares proposed in the literature, which I do not like to go through without a good knowledge.

On the other hand, there are diverse implementations of Triple Store. but really want to know how it differs from Triple Space Computing principles, and what the recommend data store framework (databases) to use with Jena.

So, I would like to be more clearer about what alternative I should use by knowing their characteristics, cons, pros , etc.

and what the right storage I should use.

any suggestion I appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, to be honest, but even it were cleared up a bit, I think this would be too broad, since you're there are no definite right or wrong answers here.  Stack Overflow is for specific technical questions, not general discussions.

Comment: I hadn't heard the term "triple space computing" before today, as far as I'm aware.  A quick Googling tells me that it's supposed to be a new approach to computing.  A triple-store is just a repository of triples.  BY analogy, you might ask the about the difference between "databases" and "database-driven programming" (applications that use centralized databases, relational modeling, etc.).